# Match elements of rows in dataframe

Tags: r, matching

I am trying to identify rows within a dataframe that are exact matches with the exception of two columns (i.e. I want to exclude two columns from the consideration of matches). Below is an example dataframe.

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1)
y = c(1,3,4,5,6,7,8,1)
z = c(1,4,5,6,7,8,9,1)
year = 1990:1997
day = c("mon","tues","wed","thurs","fri","sat","sun","sat")
data = data.frame(cbind(x,y,z,year,day))
```

In the above example, rows 1 and 8 are matches if we exclude consideration of the columns for year and day. Is there a function that allows me to do this? I have looked at the functions duplicated() and match() but they don't quite seem appropriate.

Comment: You already know the two columns or any combination of two columns in your data.frame ?

Comment: I know the columns I want to exclude from the matching criteria, yes.

Comment: What do you mean by exact matches here ? You want to see if the row has same numbers (i.e x, y and z ) or want to look at all rows and find the common numbers on the rows ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do what you want (the example data is modified for better testing):

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,2,1,1,1)
y = c(1,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,1,1)
z = c(1,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,1,2,1)
year = 1990:2000
day = c("mon","tues","wed","thurs","fri","sat","sun","sat","sat","sun","mon")
data = data.frame(cbind(x,y,z,year,day))

which(apply(data[,1:3], 1, function(x){all(tail(duplicated(x), -1))}))
# [1]  1 11
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. It identifies rows where x == y == z, while the OP asked to identify rows that are duplicates of each other, i.e. x_i == x_j and y_i == y_j and z_i == z_j. @dickoa's answer is correct in that respect.

Comment: Indeed, there are several interpretations of "exact match" as raised by @Jdbaba.

Comment: Right. The intent behind my original question was to find rows whose column values matched other rows' column values. So, a match would be (1,2,9) and (1,2,9). This would be one match. However, I also wanted the code to identify other matches (i.e. not just the (1,2,9) match).

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach in two steps, once you know the columns you want to exclude (here cols 4 and 5).

```
ind <- which(duplicated(data[,1:3], fromLast = TRUE) |
    duplicated(data[,1:3], fromLast = FALSE))
ind
## [1] 1 8

data[ind, ]
##    x y z year day
## 1 1 1 1 1990 mon
## 8 1 1 1 1997 sat
```